# Add points to database when user adds a topic

Tags: php, html, sql, database

A user can add a topic by filling in a form.

**What i want:** 
The row "punten(points)" in my database to update the score. so if the score was 10. it adds up another 10 points.

**My function:**

```
public function update_points($tabel, $query){
    $q = '';
    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        $value  = str_replace("'","&#39;",$value);
        $q .= "`".$key."` = '".$value."',";
    }

    if(isset($q) && ($q !='')) {
        $q = substr($q,0,-1);
        $this->database->query("UPDATE ".$tabel." SET punten = punten + ".$q." LIMIT 1");
        $this->database->execute();
    }   
}
```

**Html file:**

```
if(isset($_POST['react_btn'])){                              
$query['punten'] = 10;
$app->update_points('klanten', $_SESSION['klant_id'], $query);
```

Comment: You're actually getting a MySQL error. You cannot use `LIMIT` if you're using `UPDATE`.  I'd suggest using a `WHERE id = ?` instead unless you don't mind all the rows to be updated.

Comment: Depending on what library you're using to talk to your database. `->query` into an `->execute` will fail as `->query` actually already executes and therefore, there's nothing for `$this->database->execute();` to run.

Comment: I think you're using `MySQLi` as PDO doesn't have a `execute` it has an `exec` anyway, you should consider using the [->prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) method on your `$q`(not on your $tabel as you cannot prepare a table name/column name)

Comment: And finally, every good coder should utilize error reporting to help narrow down an issue. Again, if you're using MySQLi then go get your errors outputting -> http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Lol final point sorry =) Look at your method by the way, I think you may be missing something: `update_points($tabel, $query){` and `$app->update_points('klanten', $_SESSION['klant_id'], $query);`